# Truffle console: debug not showing me the code line that reverts a transaction

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging

I'm trying to deploy my own swap router on the development network. I've got a transaction hash which reverts. I'm calling

```
truffle console
```

and then, when I press enter I get undefined. I can't reach to the source of my revert. Here is my console result:

```
truffle(development)> debug 0x3f58ab46fb675dfa2e5703345e6d022e35062623890c6c6bc02db3196ccf81f6
Starting Truffle Debugger...


Addresses affected:
 0x1d25Da4e4a6968C262860C5B4F87952B2b734791 - PancakePair
 0x53c9Fff672d4a6F625724C5bFcD05CCDA17F39D9 - Token
 0x03d35617463766a2DbB3F92C490B8D6cb3CA6eCe - Token
 0xf3892cd53bA6B3A20Bf760bC4129221Ec33F25cb - Router

Commands:
(enter) last command entered (step next)
(o) step over, (i) step line / step into, (u) step out, (n) step next
(c) continue until breakpoint, (Y) reset & continue to previous error
(y) (if at end) reset & continue to final error
(;) step instruction (include number to step multiple)
(g) turn on generated sources, (G) turn off generated sources except via `;`
(p) print instruction & state (`p [mem|cal|sto]*`; see docs for more)
(l) print additional source context (`l [+<lines-ahead>] [-<lines-back>]`)
(s) print stacktrace, (e) Print recent events (`e [<number>|all]`)
(q) quit, (r) reset, (t) load new transaction, (T) unload transaction
(b) add breakpoint (`b [[<source-file>:]<line-number>]`; see docs for more)
(B) remove breakpoint (similar to adding, or `B all` to remove all)
(+) add watch expression (`+:<expr>`), (-) remove watch expression (-:<expr>)
(?) list existing watch expressions and breakpoints
(v) print variables and values (`v [bui|glo|con|loc]*`)
(:) evaluate expression - see `v`, (h) print this help

Docs: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/debug-test/use-the-truffle-debugger/




Router.sol:

147: }
148:
149: contract Router is IUniswapV2Router {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


debug(development:0x3f58ab46...)>

( HERE I PRESS ENTER)

undefined
```

If I press any letter from commands it says:

```
debug(development:0x3f58ab46...)>
n
Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined
```

How can I make this working? The debug stops at the beginning and doesn't want to lead me to the reverting code line.